# Numpy- Find Corresponding Eigenvectors of a Particular Set of Eigenvalues

Tags: numpy, svd, eigenvalue

I'm trying to figure out how to find the corresponding eigenvectors of a particular set of eigenvalues with numpy.

I'm working on a project using Singular Value Decomposition, and I need to find Truncated SVD, which is the SVD with the k-largest Singular Values.

```
desired_singular_values = sorted_singular_values[:desired_num_singular]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you compute `sorted_singular_values`?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the first question. If you need to implement the algorithm it depends on how you want to do it. I have some pages here for [eigenvalue algorithms](https://ieee754wonderland.quora.com/Eigenvalue-Algorithms-Shifted-QR-with-Deflation). If you want the eigenvalues in python. It is the following.

```
w,v = numpy.linalg.eig(A)
```

in response the truncated SVD. There is another command within the SVD

```
u,s,vh = numpy.linalg.svd(A,fullmatrices=False)
```

Seen [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) Which gives the reduced SVD